Check type of variable within a pattern match in OCaml
How do I check the type of a variable within a pattern matching in OCaml, version I currently use is 4.13, that is available online.
I found this post: OCaml: Type Checking Objects
But it doesnt really seem to solve the problem.
The sample code I tried is, here I want to get the type of x and depending of what type is it return something different
let typecheck x = 
  match #show x with 
  |"val x : int" -> "int" 
  |"val x : string" -> "string" 
  | _ -> "Undefined";;


But I get Error: Syntax error
Maybe I can re-input the output of the directive somehow in the program?

OCaml does not have runtime type information. #show is a toplevel directive that is not part of the language, it will only work as a standalone directive on the toplevel.

This is an XY problem. What's the underlying problem that you're actually trying to solvle?

You can do that with a GADT but their use case is more for returning different types depending on the type of the input. Regardless for a GADT you still need a witness so it would gain you nothing over a much simpler type my_type = Int of int | String of string.

The OCaml compiler checks type information at compile-time. At runtime that information does not exist and does not need to be checked.
The #show directive you're using is a top-level construct only, and does not exist in an actual OCaml program. The link you included in your question has to deal with OCaml objects, but you are not using objects, so that is irrelevant.
If you want a single type which can describe values containing different types of constituent data, you likely want a variant type with multiple constructors.
E.g.
type my_type = Int of int | String of string

let check_type x = 
  match x with
  | Int _ -> "int"
  | String _ -> "string"

let () =
  let x = Int 42 in
  print_endline @@ check_type x

Which prints:
int

